# Accessing the 2nd child of parent div. In the nested DIV scenario

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add a new element(div) after the second child of a parent div in the below given scenario.

```
<div id="parent"><!--Parent Div -->
  <div><!--Child 1st-->
    <div> foo  </div>
    <div> foo1 <div>
    <div> foo2 </div>
  </div>
  <!--Want to insert in here-->
<div>
```

I have tried to use the `nth-child(2)` accessing the parent with id  using `.after` but the new element created gets inserted inside the `<div>foo</div>`

I am unable to find the solution for this please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick the *direct* children divs of `#parent` only using `#parent > div`, because `#parent div` is too generic here and it'll get all multi-level children div of `#parent` , like this:

> *Note that you have a typo here `<div> foo1 <div>` using an opening div tag to close the div instead of closing tag `</div>`*

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qpqq8wk/3/)**

```js
$('<div class="new">Newly inserted</div>').insertAfter('#parent > div:first-child');
```

```css
#parent{outline:1px dashed red; padding:10px;}
#parent > div:first-child{outline:1px dotted blue; margin:5px; padding:5px;}
.new{ font-weight:bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <!--Parent Div -->
  <div>
    <!--Child 1st-->
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>foo1</div>
    <div>foo2</div>
  </div>
  <!--Want to insert in here-->
  <div>something else</div>
  <div>test div</div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `parent` refers to parent element and `element` is the element you want to insert:

```
secondChildren = null;
if(parent.children.length > 1){
    secondChildren = parent.children[1];
}
parent.insertBefore(element, secondChildren);
```